# What is the difference between FlatMapMerge, FlatMapConcat and FlatMapLatest?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm having trouble differentiating the exact difference between these three operators.

The documentation for:

- [FlatMapMerge](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-merge.html)
- [FlatMapConcat](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-concat.html)
- [FlatMapLatest](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html)

These documentation links indicate that two Flows are flatmapped into a single Flow object. I am fine with that, but I have a hard time understanding how the emissions would change between these three operators.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I went looking through the source code and found a sensible guide that I didn't find via googling. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html#flattening-flows

The guide explains the differences but it was still a bit unclear to me, so I rewrote it in my own words here.

The basic difference between the three are determined by the way in which the inner and outer flow react to new emissions from either flow. So for the given code:

```
val outerFlow: Flow<>
val flatMappedFlow = outerflow
        .flatMapXXXXX { innerFlow(it) }
        .collect { processFlatMapResult(it) }
```

**FlatMapConcat**

This operator is sequential and paired. Once the *outerFlow* emits once, the *innerFlow* must emit once before the final result is collected. Once either flow emits a Nth time, the other flow must emit a Nth time before the Nth *flatMapResult* is collected.

**FlatMapMerge**

This operator has the least restrictions on emissions, but can result in too many emissions. Every time the *outerFlow* emits a value, each of the *innerFlow* emissions are flatMapped from that value into the final *flatMapResult* to be collected. The final emission count is a multiplication of innerFlow and outerFlow emissions.

**FlatMapLatest**

This operator cares only about the latest emitted results and does not process old emissions. Every time the *outerFlow* emits a value, it is flatMapped with the latest *innerFlow* value. Every time the *innerFlow* emits a value, it is flatMapped with the latest *outerFlow* value. Thus the final emission count is a value between zero and innerFlow emissions times outerFlow emissions.

Comment: `flatMapMerge` does _not_ guarantee all `innerFlow` emissions are collected in the correct order...

Comment: I assume your definition of `flatMapConcat` is wrong. [This](https://youtu.be/WV_PYm8A4aQ) YouTube video shows that, the final emission count is product of inner and outer flows much like `flatMapMerge`. Difference is that, former emits values sequentially unlike the latter.

Comment: I'm confused. FlatMapMerge -> "final emission count is a multiplication of innerFlow and outerFlow emissions." And then FlatMapLatest -> "between zero and innerFlow emissions times outerFlow emissions". That's the same thing right? "Multiplication of X and Y" is the same as "X times Y". If there's no typo, what's the intent of including both of those statements in each description?

Answer (score 1):

**flatmapConcate** It is used to transform a flow of elements into a flow of other elements. It applies a transformation function to each element of the flow and returns a new flow that emits the transformed elements in the order in which they were produced.

Let's say you're building an app that fetches data from two different APIs, one for user information and another for user posts. You want to display a list of all the user posts along with the user's name and profile picture.

To do this, you can use Kotlin coroutines and flatMapConcat to combine the data from the two APIs into a single flow of Post objects. Here's how you could do it:

```
suspend fun getPosts(): Flow<Post> = flow {
    val users = userApi.getUsers() // Get list of users
    for (user in users) {
        val posts = postApi.getPostsForUser(user.id) // Get posts for each user
        for (post in posts) {
            val profilePicture = userApi.getProfilePicture(user.id) // Get user's profile picture
            val postWithUser = PostWithUser(post, user.name, profilePicture)
            emit(postWithUser) // Emit combined post and user data
        }
    }
}.flatMapConcat { postWithUser ->
    val imageUrl = postWithUser.userProfilePictureUrl
    val imageBitmap = downloadImage(imageUrl) // Download user's profile picture
    val postWithImage = PostWithImage(postWithUser.post, postWithUser.userName, imageBitmap)
    emit(postWithImage) // Emit post data with profile picture
}
```

**flatMapMerge :** flatMapMerge is used to transform a flow of elements into a flow of other elements, just like flatMapConcat. However, instead of emitting the output elements in the order in which they were produced, flatMapMerge emits them as soon as they are available.

Let's say you're building an app that displays a list of photos downloaded from an API. Each photo has a unique ID, and you want to display the title of the album that the photo belongs to. You can use the photo ID to fetch the album data from a separate API.

Here's how you could use flatMapMerge to combine the photo data with the album data:

```
suspend fun getPhotosWithAlbum(): Flow<PhotoWithAlbum> = photoApi.getPhotos()
    .flatMapMerge { photo ->
        albumApi.getAlbum(photo.albumId)
            .map { album ->
                PhotoWithAlbum(photo, album.title)
            }
    }
```