# Why my flow doesn't triggers, when data changes in RoomDao

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm using RoomDao with kotlin coroutines and Flow. What I'm trying to do is collect one Training with all its Exercises with all Repetitions per Exercise. Exercises and Repetitions are Flows, cuz this values can be changed and I want to observe them.
The problem is that when I updating exercises, `getTrainingExerciseLinksBy` doesn't triggers, and I don't know, why. Here is my code in UseCase:

```
suspend fun getTrainingWithExercisesAndRepetitionsBy(trainingId: Long): Flow<UiTrainingWithExercisesAndRepetitions> {
    /// This method returns Flow<List<TrainingExerciseLink>>
    return trainingExerciseLinksRepository.getTrainingExerciseLinksBy(trainingId).flatMapConcat { trainingExerciseLinks ->
        trainingExerciseLinks.map { trainingExerciseLink ->
            /// This method returns Flow<List<ExerciseRepetition>>
            repetitionsRepository.getExerciseRepetitionsBy(trainingExerciseLink.id).map { repetitions ->
                /// do some other selects for collecting data about exercise in one training
            }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
        }.zipFlows()
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
}
```

In my ViewModel I'm observing this method like this:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    useCase.getTrainingWithExercisesAndRepetitionsBy(trainingId)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .collect {
            _exercisesListLiveData.value = it.exercises
            _trainingListLiveData.value = it.trainingData
        }
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

**UPD:**
In my DAO I'm using Flows for subscribing on database's updates, like this:

```
@Dao
abstract class TrainingExerciseLinkDao {

    @Query("select * from TrainingExerciseLink where trainingId = :trainingId")
    abstract fun getTrainingExerciseLinksBy(trainingId: Long): Flow<List<TrainingExerciseLink>>

}
```

and ExerciseRepetitionsDao:

```
@Dao
abstract class ExerciseRepetitionDao {

    @Query("select * from ExerciseRepetitionEntity where trainingExerciseId = :trainingExerciseId")
    abstract fun getExerciseRepetitionsBy(trainingExerciseId: Long): Flow<List<ExerciseRepetitionEntity>>

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I found the answer, so maybe somebody will jump in the same gap and this thread will be helpful.
The problem in my code was that I used flatMapConcat. This operator waits emits from original Flow and from flatMapped Flow at one time, so in this case it will trigger callback. To fix this, **flatMapLatest** should be used. You can read more about difference between this operators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62810686/8473860).

So my code now looks like this:

```
suspend fun getTrainingWithExercisesAndRepetitionsBy(trainingId: Long): Flow<UiTrainingWithExercisesAndRepetitions> {
    /// This method returns Flow<List<TrainingExerciseLink>>
    /// Here is main change: flatMapConcat -> flatMapLatest
    return trainingExerciseLinksRepository.getTrainingExerciseLinksBy(trainingId).flatMapLatest { trainingExerciseLinks ->
        trainingExerciseLinks.map { trainingExerciseLink ->
            /// This method returns Flow<List<ExerciseRepetition>>
            repetitionsRepository.getExerciseRepetitionsBy(trainingExerciseLink.id).map { repetitions ->
                /// do some other selects for collecting data about exercise in one training
            }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
        }.zipFlows()
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using it wrong , as when database updates your `getTrainingWithExercisesAndRepetitionsBy` does not know,
to get over this issue use flows in your dao like [this example](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Habbit/blob/e534b768862eb5e0d126c293f65c27d389fa5853/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/habbit/data/local/TasksDao.kt#L28) as Room supports `Flow` then

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    viewModel.yourFunctionThatGetsDataFromRepository(trainingId)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .collect {
            _exercisesListLiveData.value = it.exercises
            _trainingListLiveData.value = it.trainingData
        }
}
```

and if more you can refer [this example](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Habbit/blob/e534b768862eb5e0d126c293f65c27d389fa5853/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/habbit/ui/main/fragment/TodoFragment.kt#L175)

Comment: Hello, @Anshul, thank you for your answer. I'm doing as you said: I'm using Flows in DAO (I updated my question, please check it).

Comment: the function `getTrainingWithExercisesAndRepetitionsBy` is not triggered when your database updates , you can  try directly accessing dao function in your viewmodel